# asp.net Rangevalidator displaying error message even though value is within range

Tags: asp.net, rangevalidator

This is the code that I am using but when I run that code it display an error message even if I put value within range.please Can anyone help me with this?

```
<tr>
                <td class="auto-style4">Password</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Pass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Pass" ErrorMessage="Please enter Password" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Pass" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Password range (1 -10)" ForeColor="Red" MaximumValue="10" MinimumValue="1"></asp:RangeValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Do you have an IdentityConfig.cs class in the App_Start folder?

Answer (score 0):

with this `RangeValidator` you are declaring that `textbox` value should be within `1 to 10` that means if you input `11` or `0` or any `integer` which is not between `1 to 10` it will show `ErrorMessage`. I think you want to check the `textbox` length between `1 to 10` then you need a `RegularExpressionValidator` like below

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegExp1" runat="server"    
 ErrorMessage="Password range (1 -10)"
 ControlToValidate="Pass"    
 ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9'@&#.\s]{1,10}$" />
```